# Can I paste a program's snippet on codepad using CPPaste vim plugin or no?

Tags: vim, plugins, copy-paste, codepad

I'm using [vim](http://www.vim.org/) lately & [codepad](http://codepad.org/). There's a [nice plugin for vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2298) which works like a charm. My problem is that, sometimes I need just to paste a function not the entire script/program.

CPPaste plugin page states: ***to send the current buffer*** to http://codepad.org, open your pasted code in your webbrowser, and copy the URL of the pasted snippet to the clipboard.

So how do I manage to set the current buffer to a specific selection of lines/rows (made with v/V for example)?

Cheers

Comment: It sounds to me like you want the [NrrwRgn](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) plugin.  I've never used it but I believe it does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [NrrwRgn](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) plug-in to create a temporary buffer with a specific sub-set of lines, and then send that to codepad:

- <kbd>V</kbd>
- Select region you want to paste
- <kbd>:NR<CR></kbd> (because of the selection the command-line will read `:'<,'>NR`)
- Split buffer opens
- <kbd>:CP<Tab><CR></kbd>

It might not be the perfect solution, but works well enough. Also, the NrrwRgn plug-in is also very useful for editing parts of big files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the detailed shortcuts example. At the beginning it looked like kinda complicated, but once I did it a couple of times worked awesomely well :-)